# how to build up connection between two parents with one child

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been stuck in this problem for hours.

As you can see the *D_ID* 8 has two *root_id* (3, 6).  The question is how to build up the relation between 3 & 6, eventuelly all *root_id* 6 should be replaced by 3.
I think there is a easier way to solve it using Python or R. Unfortnately I am not familiar with those.

can anyone help with that? any idea will be appreciated.

code for example:

```
WITH device
AS 
(
SELECT 1 AS d_id, 'D1' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS d_id, 'D2' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS d_id, 'D3' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS d_id, 'D4' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS d_id, 'D5' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS d_id, 'D6' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS d_id, 'D7' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS d_id, 'D8' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 9 AS d_id, 'D9' AS dname FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS d_id, 'D10' AS dname FROM dual
)
, connection
AS
(
SELECT 1 AS p_id, 2 AS c_id FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS p_id, 4 AS c_id FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS p_id, 5 AS c_id FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS p_id, 7 AS c_id FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS p_id, 8 AS c_id FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS p_id, 8 AS c_id FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS p_id, 9 AS c_id FROM dual
)
SELECT d.d_id, d.dname, connect_by_root(d_id) rootdeviceid, substr(sYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(d_id, '>') ,2) AS path
  FROM device D
LEFT JOIN connection c ON (d.d_id = c.c_id)
CONNECT BY prior d.d_id = c.p_id
START WITH C.p_id IS NULL
ORDER BY d.d_id
```

I hope now it should be a little bit more clear. 
[image]

Comment: lol. Maybe I should choose a more proper title. But do you have any idea about this? Is there a way to solve this by R?

Comment: I don't think any of us can understand what you're asking.  There's probably a way to do it in SQL or any number of languages but we don't know what it is you want to do.  You've shown us the table you are starting with -- can you show us the table you want to end up with?

Comment: D_ID 5... shouldn't the RootDeviseID be 4 to get a path of 3>4>5?  otherwise how do you know 5 goes though 4?  I think this illustrates the problem with 8 potentially as well.  and I think RootDeviceID is poorly named if you have multiple levels.  It works fine on 2 levels but when you get a third the root of 5 may be 3 but it has a parent of 4.  So ParentDeviseId may make more sense.  and you traverse the hierarchy to get the desired results.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I added a pic, hope it gets more clear for you.